# Cx Freeze NameError: name 'setup' is not defined

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am entirely new to Cx_Freeze i am running the setup code below that has been taken directly from the cx_Freeze Documentation in which this same code worked but i am getting this error.

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rallo\Desktop\Programs\Python 3\setup.py", line 1, in 
    setup(
NameError: name 'setup' is not defined

the code is below. Any relevant input be helpful and Greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(  name = "Pi",
version = "1.0",
description = "",
executables = [Executable("Pi.py")])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's curious because I had no error when I tried your code. You can however follow this post https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-tkinter-to-exe-with-cx-freeze/. Maybe this time will work.